# How to find the location of an opened file

Tags: macos

Imagine that I have two files of the same name in two different folders. Now, one of them is opened and I am not sure which one is that. How to find it?

I tried "save as" option and that is not helping me much.

I am using OS X Mavericks.

Comment: What App is it open in?

Comment: @Mark LibreOffice Writer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most apps you can `Command`-`Click` or `Right`-`Click` on the document's icon in the title bar of the app and it will display a drop down menu with the full path. You can select a folder from the drop down to open it in the Finder.

[image]

Comment: This also works with "secondary-click" (right-click).

Comment: I forgot about right clicking. I updated the answer.