# How to view an open file's location?

Tags: folders, file

I have a file open but don't know what folder it's in.

How can I determine it's location?

Comment: similar answer here but with screenshot that was helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139182/how-to-find-the-location-of-an-opened-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file name in window bar.